# Evaluating shutter speed in auto mode in Canon EOS DSLR

Tags: c#, edsdk, photography, canon-sdk

I have a Canon EOS 1100D/ Rebel T3, and with Canon EDSDK, I wrote a computer program to control it by my laptop.
Now I have some problems with taking photo during the day and various light range. Typically, I set camera on Manual mode and now I can set ISO on Auto mode, but Shutter Speed can't be in dynamic mode. So, I face to a serious problem.

In The Auto Mode, Camera, itself, can measure the light and set the perfect shutter speed.
I want to use it and get the value of its photometer to set the shutter speed programmatically. What is the name of its property in EDSDK and how can I use it in my program?

Thanks for your helping.

Comment: are you using my library? https://github.com/esskar/Canon.Eos.Framework

Comment: @esskar: No, I don't. This is one part of my project which I'm writing now.